# re-run until no NA occurred

Tags: r, optimization, na

I have a code that sometimes work and sometimes not (gives Na) and I would like to find a way to run the code with condition ( if the code not work re-run it until no NA occur).

This is just an example so I can re produce the work with other distribution/data /parameters

```
 mu=3;sigma=0.3;phi=0.33;n=10
 e=rnorm(n, mean = mu, sd = sigma )

 y=e[1]
for (s in 2:n){
ynew=phi*y[s-1]+e[s]
y=c(y,ynew)
}
t=2:length(y)
ll=function(par1){
sum(-dnorm(y[t], mean = par1[1]+par1[2]*(y[t-1]), sd = par1[3],log = T)) 
     }
parstar=c(mean(y),0.1,var(y))

est_par=optim(parstar,ll,method = "Nelder-Mead")
pr1a=est_par$par
Ui=pnorm(sort(y), mean = pr1a[1],sd=pr1a[3])
## I want to have a condition for Ui so that if Ui is not Na return Ui else re-run e until Ui is not NA
```

Comment: I ran your code 10000 times and `Ui` was never `NA` nor contained `NA`, although warnings were produced from `dnorm`. Please clarify.

Comment: @IanCampbell With normal i do not get Na but if I change the distribution I got NA. My original code has complicated distribution and long code for ll function thats why I give example with normal distribution. Sorry I should mention that in my question

Comment: `repeat { do_something(); x <- do_more(); if (!anyNA(x)) break; }`? It's a bit naive and will cause infinite loops if you do not write it defensively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you could write a recursive function that will check at the last step if there are any `NA` values and rerun the same function again until you get a non-NA value.

```
calculate_fun <- function(mu, sigma, phi, n) {

   e=rnorm(n, mean = mu, sd = sigma )
   y=e[1]
   for (s in 2:n){
     ynew=phi*y[s-1]+e[s]
     y=c(y,ynew)
   }
   t=2:length(y)
   ll=function(par1){
     sum(-dnorm(y[t], mean = par1[1]+par1[2]*(y[t-1]), sd = par1[3],log = T)) 
   }
   parstar=c(mean(y),0.1,var(y))
   est_par=optim(parstar,ll,method = "Nelder-Mead")
   pr1a=est_par$par
   Ui=pnorm(sort(y), mean = pr1a[1],sd=pr1a[3])
   #added a check here
   if(any(is.na(Ui))) calculate_fun(mu, sigma, phi, n) else Ui
}

mu=3;sigma=0.3;phi=0.33;n=10
calculate_fun(mu, sigma, phi, n)
```